# autorun.inf doesn't work?

Tags: usb, autorun

So I have an autorun.inf file that looks like this:

```
[AutoRun]
open=Server.exe
icon=Logo.ico
label=XXXXXX
action=Install Server
```

It gets the Icon and Label correctly, but it does not add "Server.exe" and it's text to the autoplay USB dialog...

Server.exe is top-level.

Any clues why that would be? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know that it matters in this case, but which version of Windows are you working with? Have you tried other versions?

Comment: @Dynguss Windows 7. And no, I've only tried with Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by "it's text"? Maybe you can try starting from a working configuration that does what you want. For example, I burned an Ubuntu 10 ISO to a thumbdrive:

```
[autorun]
open=wubi.exe --cdmenu
icon=wubi.exe,0
label=Install Ubuntu

[Content]
MusicFiles=false
PictureFiles=false
VideoFiles=false
```

This shows an icon and displays the text "Run wubi.exe" with "Publisher not specified" underneath it in W7. In XP, it immediately launches wubi.exe without an autoplay prompt. If you can't repro the above, maybe your system settings have drifted from the default. Wikipedia has a [pretty great article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf) on the subject which even includes the differences between OS versions and which directives are valid for which mediums (CDs, USB drives, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Autoplay from USB device is switched off by default in Windows 7. You need to configure the policy. here are the steps:

1. Click Start and in the Search box, type gpedit.msc and press Enter.
2. Now browse to Computer Configuration\ Administrative Templates\
   Windows Components\ Autoplay Policies\ Turn off Autoplay.
3. Change the value of Turn off Autoplay to disabled.

Autoplay from USB should work fine. For more information, read :

- http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Change-AutoPlay-settings
- http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Troubleshoot-AutoPlay-problems