# Trigger setup.exe when I mount an ISO

Tags: windows-installer, iso, autorun

Whenever I mount an ISO, I want the setup.exe to be triggered automatically. There is a autorun.inf file to handle this but still nothing works.

Contents of autorun.inf:

```
[autorun]
open=setup.exe
```

What am I missing here? What registry entry should I change?

Answer (score 1):

***ISO***: Have you confirmed that this is even possible from a mounted image? ([Seems not to be](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEXwqxqzkP4)). In other words, did you try to put your `autorun.inf` and friends on a DVD or a USB stick and then testing whether auto-run actually works in that configuration you are using? Please read the rest below before trying this.

***OS***: What OS is this? I believe the handling is quite different in different OSs (disabled by default in Windows 7). Does auto-run / auto-play work for other drives (test with a vendor DVD that supports auto-play)? If you are on Windows 7, you can find AutoRun in the control panel (search for `auto` in top search box) - with settings for various devices. Check the settings and change as appropriate. You can also set policies on some OS editions: [**Wayback engine recovered link**](http://web.archive.org/web/20100330122704/http://www.sevenforums.com:80/tutorials/27544-autoplay-enable-disable-autorun.html) (**method 2**). Essentially you launch `gpedit.msc` (which is not available on some OS editions, such as home edition).

[image]

***Security Software***: What security software are you running? Many security suites disable all auto-run and auto-play features of Windows - and for good reason. This used to be a leading malware vector - which is obviously a well known issue.

---

***Some Links***:

- [autorun.inf doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606609/autorun-inf-doesnt-work)
- [Creating an AutoRun-Enabled Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144206(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Troubleshoot AutoPlay problems](https://web.archive.org/web/20130312050353/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Troubleshoot-AutoPlay-problems).
- [Windows 7 autorun does not start when CD/DVD is inserted](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-hardware/windows-7-autorun-does-not-start-when-cddvd-is/1cc13660-9bf8-45a2-a848-1742c59af7bd)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf
- [How to disable the Autorun functionality in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/967715/how-to-disable-the-autorun-functionality-in-windows)
- [Fix: Autoplay Not Working in Windows 10](https://windowsreport.com/autoplay-not-working-windows-10/)
- [Creating autorun.inf - "Application not found" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52295998/creating-autorun-inf-application-not-found-error/52297002#52297002)