# Creating autorun.inf - "Application not found" error

Tags: windows, deployment, windows-installer, autorun

I didn't expect to be deploying an application through a CD installation in 2018, but here we are. I have following files on my ISO image:

```
E:
 |- autorun.inf
 |- Setup.msi
 |- CD_icon.ico
 |- setup.exe
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

The `autorun.inf` contains the following content:

```
[autorun]
icon=CD_icon.ico
label=Instal MySoftware
UseAutoPlay=1
shellexecute=Setup.msi

[Content]
MusicFiles=false
PictureFiles=false
VideoFiles=false
```

When I double click the CD file or select "Run or install program from media" I get this error dialog for this CD image:

[image]

What's wrong with my ISO file? Why is the icon not showing and the installer does not run?

Comment: Likely something else wrong, but first I'd verify if security software intervenes and blocks your CD launch. TrendMicro, Norton, Kaspersky, McAfee, ESET, Avast, AVG, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Windows 7-10 Ignoring Autorun.inf***: This wikipedia article describes differences in the handling of **`autorun.inf`** over time: [**Autorun.inf**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf#Inf_handling). And [more on AutoRun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoRun). It appears you need a real CD / DVD to test this double click. You have an ISO file? Maybe burn it to real media?

***Setup.msi***: Are you sure you can kick off an MSI like that? Don't you need a full **`msiexec.exe`** command line or better yet: a **`setup.exe`** wrapper which kicks off the installation? Tools such as Advanced Installer feature support to create such launchers. I think Installshield has it too. **UPDATE**: you probably can use an MSI file directly, since you use the `shellexecute` and not the `Open` "commands".

***Previous Answers***: Here is an older question relating to the use of ISO files: [trigger setup.exe when I mount an iso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51169066/trigger-setup-exe-when-i-mount-an-iso).

***Security Software***: And as mentioned in the comment. Many security suites disable all auto-run and auto-play features of Windows - a well known issue that I just want to mention.

Comment: Thanks, the mouted ISO was indeed part of the problem. Windows acts weird with it - the error persists even when there is no mounted CD any more. Probably caching issue. After burning, the CD worked just fine.

Comment: Great, that leaves security software interference as your primary remaining problem then - I guess. If I were you I would upload it all to [virustotal.com](http://www.virustotal.com) to check for false positives, and then run a test on a couple of computers with major security suites running. Importance of this depends on your distribution I guess (could be internal app?).